# Why does Eevee make some meshes glitch and disappear as I move away from them?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I don't see any overlapping faces.
Normals are pointing the right way.

I don't know what else to check. What causes EEVEE to do this?

[image: glitch]

Comment: Maybe you don't see overlaping faces when you are close to your model, but the size of your model isn't good and default clipping size of your camera is wrong. (in blender there is two cliping option, one for the viewport that is in the N pannel in the view section, and one in each camera) You can edit the start and end clip to adjust depending on the scale of your scene.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. Apparently setting my Clip Start to 0.001 was causing this.. I never would have thought it would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Clip Start to 0.001 is what caused this.
Setting it to something slightly higher fixes it.